# Can I use Visual Studio to track changes to tables and stored proc?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Can I use Visual Studio to track changes to tables and stored proc?

I've seen it done at a previous place but now I'm trying myself and I can't seem to find the project to add.  I am running VS2013Pro.  Could that be the issue?

Comment: Define "changes to tables and stored proc". What _kind_ of changes do you mean specifically?

Comment: We had a project in VS that pointed to a database.  We were then able to update the VS project with any changes to the table schemas, stored proc changes that were done on sql server db.

Comment: You mean a [database project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833404(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be under `Tools -> SQL Server -> New Schema Comparision...`

[image]

If you do not have that option you may need to install [Sql Server Data Tools (SSDT)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx)

Comment: Thank you.  It was missing for me.